# How to show that probability of the following given event achieve the extremes

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have an exercise where I have to show that the probability of the intersection of two sets is bounded. I have done it but I want an example to show that both extremes are possible,someone help me out,Thanks

The questions is: Let $A$ and $B$ be two events with probabilities $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ respectively. Show that $\frac{1}{12} \leq \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) \leq \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  I suggest...imagine that you are drawing a number uniformly at random from $\{1, \cdots, 12\}$.  Define your events $A,B$ accordingly.

Comment: If $B \subset A$, then $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = \mathbb P(B) = \frac 13$. And if $A \cap B = \varnothing$ then $\mathbb P(A \cap B)  = 0$...

Comment: It isn't possible for $A\cap B=\emptyset$, because then $P(A\cup B)>1$.

Comment: $\mathbb P(A\cap B)$ is minimised when $A$ and $B$ have as little "overlap" as possible. Drawing a Venn diagram can help you to visualise this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)$. Because $\mathbb{P}(A)$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)$ are given, $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$ is the smallest when $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)$ is the biggest. But $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)\leq 1$, so
$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \geq \frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{3}-1=\frac{1}{12}$. Now, $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$ is the biggest when $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$, but because $\mathbb{P}(A)>\mathbb{P}(B)$, we can only have $B\subset A$. Then $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{3}$, so in the end $\frac{1}{12}\leq \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\leq \frac{1}{3}$. Now we have to know that these bounds can be obtained, so we need to find specific examples.

- Let $\Omega=\{1,2,\ldots,12\}, A=\{1,\ldots,9\},B=\{9,10,11,12\}$. Then $\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\mathbb{P}(B)=\frac{1}{3}$ as we need. We see that $A\cap B=\{9\}$, so $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{12}$.
- Let $\Omega$ and $A$ be same as above, but $B=\{1,2,3,4\}\subset A$. Then $A\cap B=\{1,2,3,4\}=B$ and $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{3}.$

We find these examples so that we know our bounds can't be improved. We can always find trivial bounds ($0$ or $1$), but the question is can these bounds be 'better'. If we find specific example that satisfies the bound which we found, then it is in fact optimal and can't be improved.

Comment: The inequality in the work leading to $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\geqslant 1/12$ is pointing the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit it. Thanks for noticing.